# how to store two classes inherit same interface in a SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, database-design

I'm having trouble figuring out How should this be stored in a sql database

```
public interface IProduct {
    string Name { get; set; }
    decimal DoSomething();
}
public class Product1 : IProduct {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //some other properties
    //.....
    public decimal DoSomething(){...}
}
public class Product2 : IProduct {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //some other properties
    //.....
    public decimal DoSomething(){...}
}
```

if each product concrete class has its own table how to apply a get all products method?

Or should I have a BaseProduct table to store the names with a productType column and each product concrete class has its own details in another table? if that is the right way should those types be an enum in my library or there is a better way?

Comment: The problem is that you botch your design to start with. Employee is a ROLE someone has. Name is what a PERSON has. This is broken even on the object level.

Comment: #TomTom its a quick example I'll change it to Products to be more clear, thank you for your reply.

Comment: Why don't you have a base Product class that implements the interface? You can have specializations of the Product class but there's very little point in that - the difference between products is usually things like the name, description and SKU.

Comment: #slugster I have much complex product types in my system I also considered the approach you mentioned, just confused what is the best implementation, thank you for your reply.